# Webpack + git workflow with development and production version of the project

Tags: git, webpack, workflow

I wonder what's the most common or specifically your workflow with webpack + git and two different versions of the project - one for development and another one for production.

I have a production version of the project with all of the scripts such as Google Analytics, FB, ads and so on, but I don't want them in my development version. Now with git, I have 2 branches - master and development. What's the best solution to handle two versions of the same project with some differences?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for opinions?

Comment: Yes, I mean there can be a lot of ways how to do it but I want to choose the most elegant or at least less time consuming approach.